# Why we cannot open .xcodeproj file in textedit?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

What is that file? A normal text file right? I want to know what's inside.

I know that changing the name of your .xcodeproj will make it fail to compile and I think it's silly.

I want to fix it.

Comment: rename .xcodeproj with .txt

Comment: Hmm... turns out .xcodeproj is a directory

Comment: Yes it is a directory. You can view it contents by: "Show Package Contents" with right click menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the `.xcodeproj` from within XCode. With the project navigator open, click on the project file name at the root and press Enter to rename it.

Comment: I did that and got:fatal: bad source, source=BadgerNew.xcodeproj/BusinessDetail.h, destination=BadgerNew1.xcodeproj/BusinessDetail.h